# How to pop min element from std::heap?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, heap

I have a `std::vector`, that I use `std::heap` on it.

I want in a while loop, to pop the minimum value, every time the loop starts. In the body of the loop, another element will be inserted in the heap. The loop stops after a number of runs.

What came to my mind is to use `std::sort_heap` and then erase the first element. However, this doesn't seem to be a good idea. You see, speed is of real essence at this part of my code.

I don't think that this is a good idea, because I have to call `std::sort_heap` at every run, because an element is going to be inserting, thus making the `std::vector` a heap again, which means that I have to sort it again, in order the minimum element to be placed at the front.

Moreover, erasing from start, with `vector.erase()` is slower than erasing the last element, right? If I delete the first element, then all the others have to be moved one position to the left. If I delete the last, element, I just pay the cost of deletion.

That lead me to this idea, sort the vector my way, so that the minimum element will come to the end, thus paying the deletion of the last element only. However, this still requires sorting at every run of the loop, right?

Which is the optimal approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to maintain a max heap, but with the additional ability to remove the min element quickly? Or are you simply wanting a min heap?

Comment: Apparently I overkilled it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `std::heap` sorted with `std::less` makes it easy to extract the *largest* element, not the smallest.  However if you use `std::greater`, then you can efficiently extract the min element.

`std::pop_heap`, using `std::greater`, will put the minimum element at the back of the sequence, and reduce the size of the heap by one.  You can then read the `back()` and write to the `back()` with a new element.

`std::push_heap`, using `std::greater`, will insert the element at the back of a sequence, increasing the size of the heap by one.

In code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{5, 4, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3};
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>{});
    int i;
    while (std::cin >> i)
    {
        // pop minimum, and place at back()
        std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>{});
        // write min out
        std::cout << "min = " << v.back() << '\n';
        // push a new element into the heap
        v.back() = i;
        std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>{});
    }
}
```

This all quite efficient using `vector` because the extraction and insertion is actually at the back of the `vector`.  And because we're using `greater`, we actually extract the minimum element each time (which is a little non-intuitive).

If desired, the above logic can be encapsulated in a `std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>>` which simply adapts the `vector` and exposes `push`, `pop` and `top` member functions instead of `vector`'s `push_back`, `pop_back` and `back`.  This adaptor will simply call `make_heap`, `push_heap` and `pop_heap` in the appropriate places.

**Update**

[TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819272/templaterex) correctly points out that in C++14 `greater<>` can be used in place of `greater<int>`.  For example:

```
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<>{});
```

This creates a *heterogeneous* functor that can take *any* two arguments, not just `int`:

```
template <>
struct greater<void>
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    auto operator()(T1&& t, T2&& u) const
        { return std::forward<T1>(t) > std::forward<T2>(u); }
    typedef void is_transparent;
};
```

With this new feature one only has to change the `vector` to change types (well, and the type of `i`), and the rest of the example will adapt to the change in type automatically.

Comment: or in C++14: `std::greater<>{}`, makes it easier to refactor to other types

Comment: @TemplateRex could you explain in a little more detail the C++14 feature you're referring to and the benefits it provides? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @mattnewport [this working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm) or [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators)

Comment: @TemplateRex thanks, I'd heard about the heterogeneous container lookup but not the transparent comparators which actually seems more generally useful than heterogeneous lookup appeared to me initially.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want a [`std::priority_queue<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). It has `O(log n)` complexity for push and pop.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pop_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) and [push_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap). As sharth suggests you can also use the [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) container adaptor which wraps up the heap functionality with a convenient priority queue interface.

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort_heap` doesn't create a heap--rather, it takes a heap as its input, and generates fully-sorted elements as its output.

You could use a `priority_queue` as @Sharth has suggested. If you prefer to work directly with a heap, you can use `push_heap` and `pop_heap` to remove the smallest item and insert the new item respectively.

Note that unlike most algorithms, `push_heap` and `pop_heap` just rearrange items in a range. I.e., `pop_heap` moves the smallest (or largest, depending on your comparison function) item in the heap, and moves it to the end of the range, and rearranges the preceding elements into a valid heap.

Likewise, `push_heap`, takes a heap in one section of memory followed by one item in the next location in memory, and adds that element to the heap, so the entirety forms a valid heap again.