# STL priority queue in increasing order

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I need to store numbers in a queue in increasing order.
I used priority queue which stores higher value first, that is in decreasing order.

```
priority_queue<int>q;
```

Is it possible to order them increasing ?
What can i do to make the data order to be increasing ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To store value in increasing order you just need to change the declaration of the priority queue :

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> >q;
```

Comment: This solution works fine. I just need to know the significance of vector<int> in the declaration?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case, in C++14 you can do:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<>> q;
```

You can avoid `greater<int>`. That is the new way. for
more information, see [What are transparent comparators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).