# Can I access a variable's type for generic programming?

Tags: c++, templates, types, generic-programming

If I have code such as:

```
std::wstring s(L"...");
bool allCharsEqual = 
        std::find_if(s.begin(), 
                     s.end(), 
                     std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<std::wstring::value_type>(),
                                  mystring[0]))  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        == s.end();
```

I would like to have a generic expression in the marked location which would also work if I changed the variable type to `std::string`. Is this possible?

I realize I could put this in an extra function and template it with the string type, but is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `decltype` in C++11:

```
std::not_equal_to<decltype(s)::value_type>()
```

Or in C++14 you can use [*transparent comparators*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) and just skip the template argument entirely:

```
std::not_equal_to<>()
```

If you're stuck with C++03, you could make a `typedef` so that you only have a single place you need to update to change types. This is good practice in general if you can't use `auto` and have types which you forsee changing.

```
typedef std::wstring str_t
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is what your are looking for.

Since decltype is only available in C++11, maybe making your code a template would help if you have to code pre-11

```
template <typename STRING_TYPE> 
bool allCharsEqual(STRING_TYPE s){
    /* ... */
}
```