# map::find with a type that's comparable but not convertible to key_type

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

`std::map::find` accepts `const key_type&` as an argument. This way it requires the argument to be convertible to `key_type`. That seems an oversight to me because the argument doesn't have to be *convertible* to `key_type`, it only has to be *comparable* to it.

I can make an arbitrary type comparable by defining two `operator<` overloads:

```
struct A;
bool operator<(const key_type&, const A&);
bool operator<(const A&, const key_type&);
```

`map::find` should itself be a template. But it's not. So now that I'm done whining I can ask the actual question: is there a way to easily work around this and search among `map` keys by a comparable but not convertible value?

My understanding is I could use `std::find_if`, but that would be linear search instead of binary search (`O(n)` instead of `O(Log(N))`). Naturally, I don't want to implement binary search by hand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators

Comment: For C++11 I do not see any way (besides digging into the internal implementation) than altering the key_type (introducing a proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++14, `map::find` is in fact a template and works exactly as you desire (at least when the given `Compare::is_transparent` condition described below is satisfied).

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

> std::map::find
>
> C++  Containers library  std::map
>
> `iterator find(const Key& key )`; 
>   (1)
>
> `const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const`;
>   (2)
>
> `template< class K > iterator find( const K& x )`; 
>   (3)   (since
>   C++14)
>
> `template< class K > const_iterator find( const K& x ) const`;
>   (4)   (since C++14)
>
> 1,2) Finds an element with key equivalent to key.
>
> 3,4) Finds an element with key that compares equivalent to the value
>   x.  This overload only participates in overload resolution if the
>   qualified-id Compare::is_transparent is valid and denotes a type. It
>   allows calling this function without constructing an instance of Key

Comment: Okay, but if I'm stuck with a C++11 compiler, what are my options?

Comment: To be clear, `find` is only a template *if* the comparator is transparent, and the default comparator is not transparent.

Comment: Your options are to upgrade to a C++14 compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no, transparent comparators are implementable in C++11. OP just needs to use an alternative standard library with C++14 features.

Comment: @ecatmur Changing standard library seems like a *larger* commitment than changing complier.  Seems more likely to break things...

Comment: @Yakk that's dependent on circumstance. Also, you don't need a whole standard library, just the specific container. Boost.Container could be a starting point for a reimplementation; it doesn't have transparent comparators ATM, but they'd be easy enough to add, and I'm sure they'd accept an implementation if someone were to code one.