# How to avoid const cast for map access?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdmap

I have the following issue:

```
std::map<A*,double> map;

void getColor(A const * obj){
    double d = map[obj]; // does not compile wihtout const_cast<A*>(obj)
    // do something
}
```

I have a map `std::map` (somewhere) which stores pointers to objects `A`.
I have a function `getColor` which **does not** manipulate objects `A`  and so takes a pointer to a  `const A` as input.

The function `getColor` will not compile without using a const_cast.

The const cast is a design issue, but I don't know how to circumvent it if I **don't want** to make the keys in `map` **const**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why don't you want to make the keys const?

Comment: Why you don't want to make keys as `const A*` ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17639764/4181011

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767213/why-no-transparent-c1x-stdmapat

Comment: If you don't want to change the key of the `map`, you have to `const_cast`... or wait until C++14

Comment: @Gonmator I don't think C++14 can be of help here

Comment: what is different in c++14??

Comment: @Gabriel transparent/heterogenous comparators. But as pointed out in the question I linked, this won't work for map::at

Comment: @krzaq You are true: I was confused with `find()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's two possible scenarios here:

1. The function knows/expects that `obj` is already present in the map, and you're using `[]` for convenience.
2. You're using `[]` for its full potential, i.e. you expect it to add `obj` to the map if not already there.

In situation 2, you have an error in the `getColor` signature. Since it can potentially pass `obj` to a place where it will be stored as `A*`, it is wrong for it to accept a `const A*` only. Note that even if a function doesn't modify an object *itself* but passes it on somewhere where it can be modified, it is effectively modifying it indirectly and should therefore take it as non-`const`.

In situation 1, it depends on your C++ version. C++14 introduced a [template overload of `find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and related member functions of `std::map` which takes *anything comparable with `Key`* instead of only `Key`. You could therefore modify the function like this:

```
void getColor( A const * obj){
    doubel d = map.find(obj)->second;
    // do something
}
```

Note that for this to work, you also need to change the map's type to use a transparent comparator: `std::map<A*,double, std::less<>> map;` (as first pointed out by [@Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788336/1782465)).

If you're stuck with C++11 or earlier, you're out of luck and you'll have to live with the `const_cast`. Note that with a suitable comment, a `const_cast` is perfectly safe and acceptable in this case (not to mention the only way to proceed without changing the type of `map`). Again, you should use `find` or perhaps `at` instead of `[]`, since you do not want to insert into the map.

Comment: Does `less<>` do the guaranteed right thing when passed pointers?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, unlike `operator <`, `std::less` is guaranteed to work even for pointers to unrelated objects.

Comment: @angew "the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not. For template specializations `greater<void>`, `less<void>`, `greater_equal<void>`, and `less_equal<void>`, if the call operator calls a built-in operator comparing pointers, the call operator yields a total order." ok, the standard is clear here!

Comment: @Yakk Fun fact: until [very recently](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2562), the wording doesn't actually guarantee that the total orders imposed by those is consistent with the partial order imposed by the built-ins or with each other :)

Answer (score 6):

If you can afford switching to C++14 then you can configure your map to use a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) (this will work since a const pointer can be compared with a non-const pointer):

```
std::map<A*,double, std::less<>> map;
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                  enable transparent comparator on this map

void getColor( A const * obj){
    auto it = map.find(obj);
    assert(it != map.end());
    double d = it->second;
    // do something
}
```

Note that you will have to use `std::map::find()` instead of `std::map::operator[]`, since the latter [doesn't have a transparent version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768155/6394138).