# Why does std::map::at not have an overload taking a generic (homogenous) key?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap, std

Looking at cppreference, one can see that all `std::map` lookup functions (`count`, `finds`, `contains`, `equal_range`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`) have an overload taking a generic key argument (`template< class K >`) that is enabled if the comparator is *transparent*.

Why doesn't `std::map::at` offer the same overload taking a generic key type? It seems to me that `std::map<std::string, T>::at` would benefit from being able to take a `std::string_view` argument and not having to construct a temporary `std::string` key for the access.

I think it has something to do with strict weak ordering but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I failed to find the duplicate question in my initial search.

Comment: I think I'll leave my question undeleted so that the duplicate Q&A can be found via the search terms I had used.

Comment: Leaving duplicates up as "signposts" this way is the recommended approach. They are part of a redirection feature of this site. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) : *"If the question closed as a duplicate has no answers, then anonymous users will be automatically redirected to the question it is marked as a duplicate of. Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question."*

Comment: I did some sleuthing and ended up contributing an answer that attempts to resolve the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75329629/245265