# Always prefer set<T, less<>> to set<T> since C++14?

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, standards, convention

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string_view key = "hello";

    set<string> coll1;
    coll1.find(key); // error

    set<string, less<>> coll2;
    coll2.find(key); // ok since C++14
}
```

Then, should it be a rule:

**Always prefer** `set<T, less<>>` **to** `set<T>` **since C++14**?

Comment: Are you using the transparent comparitor functionality? If not, then why bother?

Comment: @ildjarn: What is "transparent comparitor functionality"?

Comment: @NicolBolas : Misspelling aside, [it's the difference between `less<>` and `less<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/636019).

Comment: @ildjarn: Oh, that's why Google failed me. Nevermind then.

Comment: `string_view` is not in C++14

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's trivial to find a counterexample:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct converts_to_string {
    operator string() const { return ""; }
};

int main()
{
    converts_to_string key;

    set<string> coll1;
    coll1.find(key); // OK

    set<string, less<>> coll2;
    coll2.find(key); // error
}
```

Comment: ... what's the reason why it doesn't work? Is it because the Standard does not require (forbid?) `operator<` on `basic_string` to be a non-member function, and therefore deduction fails? Would it work if `operator<` for `basic_string` was defined as a friend (non-template) function?

Comment: @dyp Yep, deduction failure because it's a non-member function template (and unlike `basic_string_view` doesn't have a "sufficient additional overload" rule). And yes, a friend non-template function would make this work (at the cost of one temporary string per comparison, just like your `stupid_string`).

Answer (score 10):

There can be a performance downside when using `associative_container<T, less<>>`: Consider a type like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct stupid_string
{
    stupid_string(char const* s)
      : s(s)
    { std::cout << "copy\n"; }

    stupid_string(char const* s, int) // silent
      : s(s)
    {}

    friend bool operator<(stupid_string const& lhs, stupid_string const& rhs);

private:
    std::string s;
};

bool operator<(stupid_string const& lhs, stupid_string const& rhs) {
    return lhs.s < rhs.s;
}

int main() {
    std::set<stupid_string, std::less<>> s;
    s.emplace("hello", 0);
    s.emplace("world", 0);
    s.emplace("foobar", 0);
    std::cout << "find\n";
    (void)s.find("test");
}
```

Here, the application of `operator<` in the algorithm performed by `s.find` will convert the character literal to a `stupid_string` implicitly. This happens for each comparison performed! [Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UkZN8BcXGckYgit1)

I know of one case where something similar happened in production code, with a non-conforming C++03 StdLib implementation.

---

This is by the way the main reason why heterogeneous lookup via `less<>` was made opt-in; see [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm):

> Stephan T. Lavavej suggested that the two problems of preserving
>   existing behaviour and allowing heterogeneous lookups could both be
>   solved by making the containers detect when the comparison object
>   accepts heterogeneous arguments and only conditionally overloading the
>   current lookup functions with template versions.

Comment: This is basically the reason heterogeneous lookup was made opt-in.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, but I couldn't find a quote :(