# How to ignore constness in a function template?

Tags: c++

I have the following template function:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
bool hasKey( const std::map<K, V>& m, K& k ) {
    return m.find(k) != m.end();
}
```

The keys in the map are not `const`.

Now, I may have a `const K`. How can I write a template that would allow me to pass in both `K and`const K` to the function?

Is the solution to use a `const_cast` every time I call the function?

Comment: change `K&` to `const K&` ?

Comment: Maybe you'll get better results using a third template parameter for the item to search; then implicit conversions will be enabled from that parameter to `K`

Comment: but if I pass in a const K, it still wouldnt match my map key type, would it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... have you tried it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename K>
bool hasKey(const std::map<Key, Value>& mp, const K& k) {
    return mp.find(k) != mp.end();
}
```

This way you are sure when looking at the declaration of the function that neither operand is going to be modified since they are both references to `const`.

Both non-const and const references (and even rvalues) to key types can be passed to the `.find()` methods in `std::map`.  This works because the `.find()` method accepts a key type by const reference, so if you pass a non-const reference it gets bound by a const reference anyway, so it doesn't make a difference.

Another thing that you get from templating the key types separately is compatibility with transparent comparators (since C++14, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).  For more on what transparent comparators are see [What are transparent comparators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).

Answer (score 3):

You could have `hasKey` based on a concept of `Map`:

```
template<typename Map>
bool hasKey(const Map& m, const typename Map::key_type& k) {
    return m.find(k) != m.end();
}
```