# Change std::set to find item by T type

Tags: c++, templates, stdset

```
template<class T>
class State {
    T state;
    double cost = 0;
    State<T> *cameFrom = nullptr;
```

I have this template class, and i want to create a `std::set<State<T>>`

the `<` operator of the class returns `this.cost < other.cost`

the `==` operator of the class returns `this.state == other.state`

lets say i want to check if a `State<T> x` is in a set

how can i make the set to return an iter !- end()(calling `set.find(x)`) iff the set contains a `State<T>` with the same `state(x.state)` as `x`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements of std::set by custom comparison with value of different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176182/find-elements-of-stdset-by-custom-comparison-with-value-of-different-type)

Comment: I question the idea of a type where `a < b` and `a == b` can be true at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` does not care about `operator==`, it uses an equivalence relation defined to have the same results as

```
bool equiv(T a, T b)
{
    if (a < b) return false;
    if (b < a) return false;
    return true;
}
```

If you have `State<T>` values with differing `state` but equal `cost`, only one of them can go in your `std::set`.

You might have success with a [`boost::multi_index_container`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), where you can look things up by *either* `cost` or `state`

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
using state_set = boost::multi_index_container<State<T>, 
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<State<T>, double, &State<T>::cost>>,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::member<State<T>, T, &State<T>::state>>
    >
>;

state_set set = ...;
auto & states_view = set.nth_index<1>();
if (auto it = states_view.find(x); it != states_view.end())
    ...
```