# C++ class template specialization for functors

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

The `std::set` has the below template parameters:

```cpp
template<typename _Key, typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>,
         typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Key> >
class set
```

And `std::greater` has the below template parameter:

```cpp
template<typename _Tp>
struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
```

The below declarations can both be compiled on gcc 7.1. I don't understand why the second declaration is valid. Is it a C++14 feature? Is the rule defined somewhere in the standard?

```cpp
std::set<int, std::greater<int>> s1;
std::set<int, std::greater<>> s2;
```

Comment: It *is* a C++14 feature. The specification speaks lots: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a C++14 standard library feature called [transparent comparators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).

> *The below declarations can both be compiled*
>
> ```
> std::set<int, std::greater<int>> s1;
> std::set<int, std::greater<>> s2;
> ```

The second variant allows for a *heterogeneous comparison*. Not a big deal in the case of `int` but consider the example from N3657:

```
std::set<std::string> s = /* ... */;
s.find("key");
```

In old C++11 this will construct a `string` temporary in order to 
invoke `less(string, string)`.

With a transparent comparator in C++14, `less::operator() (const string&, const char*)`<sup>1</sup> will be generated automatically which will invoke `bool operator< (const string&, const char*)`, thus avoiding the temporary.

The way it's implemented is:

```
template< class T = void >
struct greater;

template <> struct greater<void> {
  template <class T, class U> auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
    -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) > std::forward<U>(u));
};
```

That is, when no `T` is specified, it defaults to `void`, which in C++14 has a specialization that accepts heterogeneous parameters. The assumption here is that no-one would use `std::greater<void>` in older code, so the risk of existing code breaking is small.

For more details see the proposals [N3421](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm), which introduces the "diamond operators", and [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm), which introduces `std::is_transparent`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Disclaimer: the exact deduced types may be different, this is just to illustrate the core concept without getting into too much detail.</sub>

Comment: `less<string, const char*>` -- not quite true, but close enough.

Comment: @Yakk - was trying to remain readable. But you're right, updated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a C++14 feature?

[Yes, it is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater):

```
template< class T >
struct greater; // Until C++14

template< class T = void >
struct greater; // Since C++14
```

Without type `T` specified, it gets the default one, `void`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the rule defined somewhere in the standard?

From [comparisons.greater](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/comparisons.greater):

```
template<class T = void> struct greater {
  constexpr bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
};
```