# Function template and ambigous template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stdmap

I have several `std::map<some_type, some_other_type>` and I'm trying to write a function template `Lookup` as shown below.

The function template works fine when the key is a pointer or a scalar, but if the key is `std::string` there are problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

// Usage :
//   bool valueisinmap = Lookup(themap, thekey, thevalue);
template <typename TK, typename TV>
bool Lookup(std::map<TK, TV>& map,  TK key, TV& value)
{
  auto it = map.find(key);
  if (it != map.end())
  {
    value = it->second;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair("2", "two"));

    std::string x;
    std::string key = "2";

    if (Lookup(m, key, x))
      std::cout << "OK\n";

    if (Lookup(m, "2", x))  // problem here
      std::cout << "OK\n";
}
```

I understand why `Lookup(m, "2", x)` doesn't compile because the type of `"2"` is not `std::string` but is there a way to write the function template so I can use `Lookup(m, "2", x)` as well as `Lookup(m, key, x)`, `key` being a `std::string`?

And if yes this raises a second question:

```
bool Lookup(std::map<TK, TV>& map,  TK key, TV& value)
```

`key` is passed by value and if the type of `key` is `std::string`, a copy is made. Is there a way to pass `key` by reference (or some C++14 and plus magic) and still being able to use  `Lookup(m, "2", x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things here. First, the key type can be deduced seaparately (`typename K` below). Second, you want to pass the key as `const`-qualified reference and setup the map with a C++14 transparent comparison function (`typename Comp` below) to avoid unnecessary copies (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/9593596) for details about transparent comparators).

```
template <typename TK, typename TV, typename Comp, typename K>
bool Lookup(const std::map<TK, TV, Comp>& map,  const K& key, TV& value)
{
   // Same as before...
}

std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<>> m;
```

Specifying `std::less<>` as the `std::map` comparison type makes sure that overloads #3 and #4 of [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) are available.

Note that I have additionally `const`-qualified the map parameter itself, as the `Lookup` template doesn't modify it.

Comment: In other words do I need to declare `std::map<std::string, some_type, std::less<>> m;` rather than `std::map<std::string, some_type> m;` each time the key is a `std::string`?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I would not go so far, only in case you are not prepared to pay for the implicit conversion from a non-`std::string` key to `std::string` when performing lookup should you use a transparent comparator.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to introduce a separate type parameter for the key type, as follows:

```
template <typename TKM, typename TK, typename TV>
bool Lookup(const std::map<TKM, TV>& map, const TK& key, TV& value)
{
  auto it = map.find(key);
  if (it != map.end())
  {
    value = it->second;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

As long as `TK` is implicitly convertible to `TKM`, `Lookup` can be called with a key of type `TK` in conjunction with a map that has key type `TKM`.

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce another template parameter for `key` as [@Ton van den Heuvel answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58182849/3309790), another way is to exclude it from [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

```
template <typename TK, typename TV>
bool Lookup(std::map<TK, TV>& map, const std::type_identity_t<TK>& key, TV& value)
```

Then `TK` will be only deduced from the 1st parameter `map`; if you pass a `const char[]` to the function as `key` it'll be converted to `std::string` then passed as the argument. And you can make is pass-by-const-reference to avoid potential unnecessary copy.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/otTsXhen2DalnnJ6)

<sup>BTW: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is supported from C++20; if your compiler doesn't support it, you can make your own easily.</sup>

```
template<typename T> struct type_identity { typedef T type; };
```

Comment: What will be the value of `key` in this case? Is `std::type_identity_t<TK>` not an empty struct?

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel `std::type_identity` has only one member type, `std::type_identity_t<TK>` is same as `TK` in fact, they all refer to the type `TK`, except that it makes the template parameter non-deducible, then `TK` will be deduced from the 1st parameter only, the ambiguity in type deduction is avoided.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, interesting solution.

Comment: Could not get it compiled with C++17.