# The method find of a set of none const values cannot be called with const values. Can const_cast be used to solve that problem?

Tags: c++, set, constants

Let us say that p below has to be a pointer to const X. Then it is not possible to call find for a set of pointers to X with my special compare class. Is that a shortcoming of 'set' and 'find'? Is it safe to solve it with const_cast as I have done?

```
struct X{
    std::string key;
    X(std::string s): key(s) {}
};
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const X* lhs, const X* rhs) const {
        return lhs->key < rhs->key;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::set<X*,compare> m;
    const X a("hello");
    const X*p=&a;
    std::set<X*,compare>::const_iterator it=m.find(const_cast<X*>(p));
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++14 or above?

Comment: Yes I am using C++17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use of `const_cast` is safe, but any usage of `const_cast` is scary. `const_cast` is legal so long as you don't modify the object through the cast, which `std::set::find` does not do.

However, you don't need a `const_cast` here. If you make your [comparator transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/1896169), that opts into allowing [`find` to search based on anything comparable to the key type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find). This is exactly what we want:

```cpp
struct compare {
    using is_transparent = void; // doesn't matter which type you use

    bool operator() (const X* lhs, const X* rhs) const {
        // You might want to consider using std::less<X*> to compare these.
        // std::less<T*> can compare pointers which are not part of the
        // same array, which is not allowed with just a simple less-than
        // comparison.
        return lhs->key < rhs->key;
    }
};
```

Complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/NsZccs