# set with multipart key

Tags: c++, c++11, set

Say I have an object with key fields `a` and `b`.  I order them in order of `a`; should `a` be equal, then compare `b`.

I have a `set` of pointers to such objects.  I make a compare function that compares `a` and if necessary `b`.  I can `insert` and `delete` a pointer to an object.

How do I do a `find`, though, given values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: What is the C++ version you are using (this is directly supported in C++14 and later, with just a little bit of glue and duct tape)? Also, do you mean that your set uses a comparator class that compares pointers to your objects by dereferencing them, and comparing the pointed-to objects' `a` and `b`?

Comment: C++11, and yes.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy solution for C++11, only C++14 and later. In C++11 you'll have to create a dummy object with the values of `a` and `b`, and `find()` a pointer to it.

Comment: ...while there is so-called [transparent compare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/7478597) since C++14.