# Implement multi-dimensional std::map with std::tuple and view access

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap, stdtuple, nested-map

I know that I can create a multi-dimensional map by nesting maps together, e.g.:

```
// Two-dimensional key
map<string, map<int, double> > m;
```

so it is easy to extract all of the values associated to the highest order key.
So if I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
A1 : 23.0
A2 : 45.3
A5 : 5.88
B9 : 7.2
B10 : 79.74
```

I could store it as `std::map<std::string, std::map<uint, float>> mymap` and easily retrieve all of the `A` values by doing `mymap["A"]`.

I also know I can create a `std::map` with multiple keys by using a `std::tuple`, which is more intuitive:
`std::map<std::tuple<std::string,uint>, float> mymap`

but is there a `c++14` way to get all of the `A` elements with this second implementation?

Comment: you can use `lower_bound` or alike.

Answer (score 2):

> `std::map<std::tuple<std::string,uint>, float> mymap`

<sup>I'm assuming `uint` means `unsigned int`.</sup>

For this particular case, `map::lower_bound` and `map::upper_bound` may be combined:

```cpp
auto beg = mymap.lower_bound({"A",0});
auto end = mymap.upper_bound({"A", static_cast<unsigned>(-1)});

for(auto it = beg; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->second << '\n'; // only "A" records
}
```

- `lower_bound` will return an iterator to the first element not less than the given key, which is the first possible valid `A` entry, `{"A", 0}`.
- `upper_bound` will return an iterator to the first element greater than the given key, which is the last possible valid `A` entry, `{"A", (unsigned) -1}`.

Comment: `map::equal_range` could also be used

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `equal_range` uses the built in comparator, so you can't specify just give me al `"A"`s without building a custom transparent comparator for the map.

Comment: @NathanOliver And? It's not difficult to make one https://godbolt.org/z/djsGb4eeK

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::map::equal_range`. It requires you to provide a transparent comparator, which is easy to make:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using Key = std::pair<std::string, int>;

struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(Key const& e1, std::string const& e2) const noexcept {
        return e1.first < e2;
    }

    bool operator()(std::string const& e1, Key const& e2) const noexcept {
        return e1 < e2.first;
    }

    bool operator()(Key const& e1, Key const& e2) const noexcept {
        return e1 < e2;
    }

    using is_transparent = bool;
};

int main() {
    std::map<Key, float, Cmp> map;

    map.insert({{"A", 1}, 23.0F});
    map.insert({{"A", 2}, 45.3F});
    map.insert({{"A", 5}, 5.88F});
    map.insert({{"B", 9}, 7.20F});
    map.insert({{"B", 10}, 79.74F});

    auto const rng = map.equal_range("A");
    for (auto it = rng.first; it != rng.second; ++it) {
        std::printf("%s%d : %.2f\n", 
                    it->first.first.c_str(), 
                    it->first.second,
                    it->second);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Some info about [transparent comparators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators)