# Make object searchable with two different keys

Tags: c++

Given a class with two keys:

```
class A {
    int key1;
    int key2;
    byte x[]; // large array
}
```

If multiple objects of class `A` are instantiated and I want to sort them by `key1`, I can insert them into an `std::set`.

But if I want to sort these objects both by `key1` and by `key2`, how would I do that?

I could create two sets where one set sorts by `key1` and the other set sorts by `key2`, but that doubles the amount of memory used. How can I avoid this?

Edit 1:

As far as I know, when an object is inserted into a set, the object is copied. So if I create two sets (one sorted by `key1` and one sorted by `key2`), that means two versions of the object will exist: one in `set1` and one in `set2`. This means that member `x` also exists twice, which unnecessarily doubles the amount of memory used.

Edit 2:

To give a more specific example: given the class `Person`.

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    // other fields
}
```

I want to be able to find people either by their name and by their address. Both keys won't be used at the same time: I want to be able to call `find(name)` and `find(address)`.

Also, objects of the `Person` class won't be added or removed from the datastructure that often, but lookups will happen often. So lookups should ideally be fast.

Edit 3:

Storing pointers to the objects in the `set` instead of the objects themselves seems like a good solution. But would it be possible to store pointers in both sets? I.e.

```
std::set<A*> set_sorted_by_key1;
std::set<A*> set_sorted_by_key2;

A *obj_p = new A();

set_sorted_by_key1.insert(obj_p);
set_sorted_by_key2.insert(obj_p);
```

Comment: "but that doubles the amount of memory used" - indices aren't free, unfortunately. You want to introduce orderings that are completely unrelated to each other, so I am afraid you'll need to use some additional memory to hold that data in. Of course you can store references to those large objects, or make the objects themselves store references to "large array", thus only doubling the index space.

Comment: `boost::multindex` might be a solution for you.

Comment: What is your exact use case for this? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: depends on more details. Could be an option to store the instances in a `std::vector<A>` sort it with respect to `key1`, then use a `std::set<A*>` sorted with respect to `key2` with pointers pointing to elements of the vector. Doesn't work (easily) when you need to add / remove elements

Comment: Store the objects themselves in one of the sets and pointers to the objects in the second set. Then it’s not exactly “doubling the memory used”. Of course there will always be a memory overhead for each additional index you need.

Comment: Write a custom comparison operator..?

Comment: your clarification is about what you do not want. I think this was clear before. What is a little unclear is what you do want. Why do you need two different orderings? Do you need to add / remove elements frequently? Is `O(log(N))` look-up absolutely necessary for both ways? How much additional memory would be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Storing pointers to the objects in the set instead of the objects themselves seems like a good solution. But would it be possible to store pointers in both sets?

Sure, your sets seem to share ownership of that objects, so:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    // other fields
};

using PersonPtr = std::shared_ptr<Person>;
```

Now you want to sort them by name:

```
struct CmpName {
    using is_transparent = void;
    
    bool operator()( const PersonPtr &p1, const PersonPtr &p2 ) const { return p1->name < p2->name; }
    bool operator()( const std::string &s, const PersonPtr &p2 ) const { return s < p2->name; }
    bool operator()( const PersonPtr &p1, const std::string &s ) const { return p1->name < s; }
};

std::set<PersonPtr,CmpName> byName;
```

Note type alias `using is_transparent = void;` and two additional methods are to enable equivalent search in `std::set` otherwise you would have to create instance of `std::shared pointer<Person>` just to to lookup. Details can be found here [What are transparent comparators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators/20318064#20318064)

And search it:

```
auto f = byName.find( "John" );
```

Here how it works: [Live example](https://ideone.com/8cajgP)

Searching by address can be done very similar way, just add another comparator struct and initialize `std::set` with it.

Though you can store object and have multiple indexes using `boost.multiindex` but it has learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

Finding an element in a sorted vector via `binary_search` is `O(log(N))` just as `std::set::find` is `O(log(N))`, hence if you want to stay with standard containers, concerning time complexity of finding elements, the type of container you actually choose isnt that important.

Concerning the additional memory, you wont get it any cheaper than storing an additional pointer to the elements somewhere.

So what you can do is

```
 std::vector<A> sorted1;
 std::sort(sorted1.begin(),sorted1.end(), 
           [](const A& a,const A& b) { return a.key1 < b.key2; });

 std::vector<A*> sorted2;
 // ... fill with pointers to elements in sorted2
 std::sort(sorted2.begin(),sorted2.end(), 
           [](A* a, A* b) { return a->key2 < b->key2; });
```

Comment: Using pointers seems like the way to go for me. But could I store pointers in both sets/verctors (see edit 3 of my question)?

Comment: "the type of container you actually choose isnt that important." yea right, then you add elements to `sorted1` and boom.

Comment: @Slava wasnt happy with that wording either. Tried to fix it

Comment: @PieterV why not ?