# Time complexity for std::find_if() using set in C++

Tags: c++, function, set, find

What is time complexity for std::find_if() function using std::set in C++?

Consider we have the following example:

```
auto cmp = [&](const pair<int, set<int>>& a , const pair<int, set<int>>& b) -> bool {
    if (a.second.size() == b.second.size()) {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
    return a.second.size() < b.second.size();
};
set<pair<int, set<int>>, decltype(cmp)> tree(cmp);
...
int value = ...;
auto it = find_if(tree.begin(), tree.end(), [](const pair<int, int> &p) {
    return p.first == value;
});
```

I know it takes std::find_if O(n) to work with std::vector. Can't see any problems for this function not to work with std::set with time complexity O(log(n)).

Comment: `std::find_if` is equal opportunity because it can't take advantage of any special magic from the container. It just goes from iterator to iterator loo king for a match https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find#Complexity

Comment: @user4581301 Make that an answer (it's literally the exact answer).

Comment: Good point. I keep forgetting I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity for `std::find`, `std::find_if`, and `std::find_if_not` is `O(N)`.  It does not matter what type of container you are using as the function is basically implemented like

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first)) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

Which you can see just does a linear scan from `first` to `last`

If you want to take advantage of `std::set` being a sorted container, then you can use `std::set::find` which has `O(logN)` complexity.  You can get a `find_if` type of behavior by using a [comparator that is transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).

Comment: `std::find_if` is `O(n)` only, if the amoritized cost of incrementing the iterator and the amortized cost of dereferencing the iterator are both `O(1)`. It's possible to implement containers where this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

`std::find_if` is equal opportunity because it can't take advantage of any special magic from the container. It just iterates the container looking for a match, so worst case is always O(N).

See [documentation for `std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find#Complexity) starting at the section on Complexity and pay special attention to the possible implementations.

Note that `std::find_if`'s actual performance will likely be MUCH worse with a `set` than that of a `vector` of the same size because of the lack of locality in the data stored.