# Searching for a non-cost pointer in an STL set using a const argument

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a set of pointers to a class:

```
std::set<myclass*> myset
```

In a function that gets a const myclass* ss argument, I want to search whether **myset** contains **ss**:

```
bool item_in_set( const myclass *ss ) {
  return myset.find( ss ) != myself.end();
}
```

This fails with an '*argument would lose const qualifier*' error.
Although it makes sense, I would expect that std::set has a way to search for items using a const qualifier but I can't find anything. To make this work I used:

```
bool item_in_set( const myclass *ss ) {
  return myset.find( const_cast<myclass*>( ss ) ) != myself.end();
}
```

This works but is clunky and I'm concerned that I'm missing something.

Is there a better way to do this, or any risks with my approach?

I don't want to change the signature of item_in_set() as it's pretty far in the call stack of other functions with a *const myclass** signature (I have simplified the names in this example).

I'm using C++17.

Comment: Storing pointers as keys in sets or maps is problematic, since it's the actual *pointer* that's the key, not the object the pointers are pointing to. So if you have two `myclass` objects: `myclass a, b;` and they otherwise compare equal (i.e. `a == b` is true, assuming there's a suitable `==` operator defined), then `&a` will not be equal to `&b`. And it's those pointers that are stored in the set.

Comment: A constant object can't be converted to a non-constant object without an explicit `const_cast`. The same goes for pointers to objects: Pointers to constant object (i.e. `const myclass*`) can't be implicitly converted to a pointer to a non-constant object (i.e. `myclass*`). You must either change the signature (which isn't practical in your use-case) or use the `const_cast` (which is safe for this use-case).

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) fixes this:

```
std::set<myclass*, std::less<>> myset;
```

It's a good idea to use it by default for all your sets/maps.

It makes `.find()` a template, accepting any type comparable with the element type.

For some reason, it doesn't affect some of the functions (such as `.at()`); for those I'd continue using `const_cast`.

Comment: Does not work if you cannot change the type of the set

Comment: @Lasersköld In that case you have to `const_cast`.

Comment: Or you can do a linear search, it's up to you.

Comment: @Lasersköld You can, but you shouldn't. The only problem with `const_cast` here is that it's aesthetically unpleasant, and you shouldn't pay with performance just for aesthetics. (Also, I guess I should've downvoted without commenting - lession learned. :/)

Comment: @Lasersköld *"cannot change the type of the set"* Are they? As I read it, they only don't want to change the function signature.

Comment: They do not talk about performance either...

Answer (score -1):

Wow, really wierd problem.

[One workaround](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cset%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Astruct+myclass+%7B%7D%3B%0Astd::set%3Cmyclass*%3E+myset%3B%0A%0Abool+item_in_set(+const+myclass+*ss+)+%7B%0A++++return+std::find(+myset.begin(),+myset.end(),+ss+)+!!%3D+myset.end()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27180%27)),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) is to use `std::find(...)` although it might affect performance.

```cpp
    return std::find( myset.begin(), myset.end(), ss ) != myset.end();
```

Comment: Doing a linear search just to a avoid a `const_cast` is silly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thats your opinion. I never said it was a perfect idea, but sometimes you do not have control over the type and performance of the find operation is not a problem. Then it would be a adequate solution.